# Why am I not allowed to use the character  in a Java source code file as a variable name?

Tags: java, character-encoding, compilation

What are the rules for the characters that can be used in Java variable names?

I have this sample code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int k = 4;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

which will not compile:

```
javac Main.java
Main.java:3: error: illegal character: '\udd1e'
        int k = 4;
              ^
1 error
```

So why is the Java compiler throwing an error for '' ? (\uD834\uDD1E)

Same in ideone.com: http://ideone.com/fnmvpG

Comment: Which encoding you have set in your IDE?

Comment: @Jens I am not using any IDE. This is just a simple text file, I am compiling from terminal. The file itself is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: And the encoding setting of your commandline?

Comment: @Jens utf-8. Does it work for you? Is it about my environment you say?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) in the identifier.

Comment: In particular, the problem is that the character you're trying to use isn't a valid character as per the rules I've given in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the rules for the characters that can be used in Java variable names?

The rules are in the JLS for identifiers, in [section 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). You're interested in [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-int-):

> A character may be part of a Java identifier if any of the following are true:

- it is a letter
- it is a currency symbol (such as '$')
- it is a connecting punctuation character (such as '_')
- it is a digit
- it is a numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
- it is a combining mark
- it is a non-spacing mark
- isIdentifierIgnorable(codePoint) returns true for the character

Of course, that assumes you're compiling your code with the appropriate encoding.

The character you're apparently trying to use is [U+1D11E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d11e/index.htm), which is none of the above. It's a musical treble clef, which is in the "Symbols, other" category.